# Mat-Icon name List

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am looking to put all of the mat-icons from: https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline
into a select box. However, I can't seem to find a list of just the icon names. I figured I would
ask if anyone knew of one, or even better a JSON list on the official website?
Also, the matIconRegistry doesn't seem to have a get function 
Any ideas? Or am I copying them all my self?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have opened the network console when acessing the site which shows a request with this url: https://fonts.google.com/metadata/icons